# Serverless with TypeScript, convert from plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a code in JavaScript that I want to convert to TypeScript

Currently I have this two files:

`API_Responses.js`

```
const Responses = {
  _200(data = {}) {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
  }
};

module.exports = Responses;
```

`getData.js`

```
const Responses = require('./API_Responses');

exports.handler = async event => {
    const response = {
      payload: event?.pathParameters || ''
    }

    return Responses._200(response);
};
```

And the `serverles.yml` file to deploy that lambda function is:

```
functions:
  getData:
    handler: getData.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: get-data/{ID}
          method: GET
          cors: true
```

I want to use `ts` files and `import` ES6 methods.

So I tried this changes:

`API_Responses.ts`

```
export const Responses = {
  _200(data = {}) {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
  }
};
```

`getData.ts`

```
import Responses from './API_Responses';

// But here I'm confused
const handler = async event => {
    const response = {
      payload: event?.pathParameters || ''
    }

    return Responses._200(response);
};

export default handler;
```

`serverless.yml`

```
functions:
  getData:
    handler: getData.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: get-data/{ID}
          method: GET
          cors: true
```

With this way I get the error: "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'getData'",

Comment: You probably will need to use `getData.default`. Look at the transpiled js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seemed to change your `serverless.yml` file between those two versions (vanilla javascript and typescript version).

The name of the function that is called is still "handler", yet in the `serverless.yml` file you are calling "getData" (corresponding to the file name)

Serverless framework is build around plain javascript functions, that are deployed. It doesn't know about your filenames once its compiled.

If you are using ts-node or if you are compiling your `.ts` files manually, you can always check the generated output source code, that will be executed.